# Why write from databricks spark notebook ( hadoop fileUtils) to DBFS mount location is 13 times slower than write to DBFS Root location?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, databricks, azure-databricks

Databricks notebook is taking 2 hours to write to /dbfs/mnt (blob storage).
Same job is taking 8 minutes to write to /dbfs/FileStore.

I would like to understand why write performance is different in both cases.
I also want to know which backend storage does /dbfs/FileStor uses?

I understand that DBFS is an abstraction on top of scalable object storage.
In this case it should take same amount of time for both /dbfs/mnt/blobstorage and /dbfs/FileStore/.

**Problem statement:**

Source file format : .tar.gz

Avg size: 10 mb

number of tar.gz files: 1000

Each tar.gz file contails around 20000 csv files.

**Requirement :**
Untar the tar.gz file and write CSV files to blob storage / intermediate storage layer for further processing.

unTar and write to mount location (Attached Screenshot):

Here I am using hadoop FileUtil library and unTar function to unTar and write CSV files to target storage (/dbfs/mnt/ - blob storage).
it takes 1.50 hours to complete the job with 2 worker nodes (4 cores each) cluster.
[image]

Untar and write to DBFS Root FileStore:
Here I am using hadoop FileUtil library and unTar function to unTar and write CSV files to target storage (/dbfs/FileStore/ )
it takes just 8 minutes to complete the job with 2 worker nodes (4 cores each) cluster.
[image]

**Questions:**
Why writing to DBFS/FileStore or DBFS/databricks/driver  is 15 times faster that writing to DBFS/mnt storage?

what storage and file system does DBFS root (/FileStore , /databricks-datasets , /databricks/driver ) uses in backend? What is size limit for each sub folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple factors affecting that, but it requires more information to investigate:

- your `/mnt` mount point could point to the blob storage in another region, so you have higher latency
- you're hitting a throttling for your blob storage, for example, if there are a lot of reads/writes or list operations to it from other clusters - this may lead to retry of the Spark tasks (check Spark UI if you had any tasks with errors). On other side, the `/FileStore` is located in a dedicated blob storage (so-called [DBFS Root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#dbfs-root)) that is not so loaded.

Usually, for DBFS Root the Azure Blob Storage is used, not ADLS. ADLS with hierarchical namespace have an additional overhead for operations because it needs to check permissions, etc. This could also affect performance.

But to solve that problem it's better to open a support ticket as it may require backend investigation.

P.S. Please note that DBFS Root should be used only for temporary data, as it's accessible only from workspace, so you can't share data on it with other workspaces or other consumers.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and sharing the details. I have already raised support ticket with azure databricks team. Azure storage team confirmed that that there is no throttling while writing to /mnt location. My /mnt location is in West US and Databricks workspace and storage account created by Databricks works are in East US. I will create new storage account in East US , where databricks is located and re-run the job to see performance.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have created a storage account in same region (East US) where databricks is located (East US) . I can see that it take 8 minutes now to write data to /mnt/ location.

Comment: Hi Alex, I would like to understand why databricks takes 13x more time to write data to different region storage compared to same region storage account?
What is API / protocol does databricks uses in backend to write data to same region and different region?
This is very important for us to get clarified because we are developing service for customers.
Customer can choose storage account region and data bricks account region while deploying this service in their subscription.
If both are different regions, then customer will face performance issues as I reported.

Comment: Databricks uses standard protocols provided by azure.  There are many moving pieces that requires careful debugging and analysis, so imho it’s outside of scope of stackoverflow - involve solution architect or partner solution architect working with your company